# PHP code how to clean user input from $_POST

Tags: php, post, sanitization

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    $score11 = $_POST['passmarks12'];

    if($_POST['passmarks12'] > 100){
        $grade11 = "";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['passmarks12'] < 45){
        $grade11 = "Fail";
    }
    $strg = " $grade11";

    echo $strg;

?>
```

The code is always printing "Fail" regardless of what is sent in.

I want it so that if it passes in blank or invalid input it fails.

And how should I properly cleanse the input?

Comment: If you can't trust the inputs to be valid, you check them _before_ doing anything else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This PHP code will make sure `$_POST` is not empty before comparing it to 100.

```
<?php
    $score11 = $_POST['passmarks12'];

    if(empty($_POST['passmarks12']) || $_POST['passmarks12'] > 100)
        $grade11 = "";

    elseif ($_POST['passmarks12'] < 45)
        $grade11 = "Fail";

    $strg = " $grade11" ;

    echo $strg;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

    //$_POST['passmarks12'] = '';

    if(empty($_POST['passmarks12']) || $_POST['passmarks12'] > 100)
    {
        $grade11 = "";
    }

    else if ($_POST['passmarks12'] < 45){

        $grade11 = "Fail";
    } else{
            $grade11 = "Pass";
    }
    $strg = " $grade11" ;

    echo $strg;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Points:

1. Check if `$_POST['key']` exists using `isset`.
2. Check if `$_POST['key']` has a valid data type, **string**.
   It may come as **array**.
3. Check if `$_POST['key']` has a valid numeric format.
4. Compare `$_POST['key']`**(String)** and `45`**(Integer)**, using `intval`.

## Example:

```
<?php

switch (true) {

    case !isset($_POST['passmarks12']):
    case !is_string($score = $_POST['passmarks12']):
    case !is_numeric($score):
        $result = 'Error (Invalid parameter)';
        break;
    case (intval($score) < 45):
        $result = 'Fail (Less than 45)';
        break;
    default:
        $result = 'Success (No less than 45)';

}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
elseif ($_POST['passmarks12'] < 45 && !empty($_POST['passmarks12']))
```

Comment: Those should be the other way around, otherwise you get an error if `$_POST['passmarks12']` isn't set.